# VBA - Adding a custom object to a collection in a loop

Tags: vba, excel, object, for-loop

I have create a *Node* Object:

```
Public value As Integer
Public marked As Boolean

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
     value = 0
     marked = False
End Sub
```

Then I tried to add some *Node Objects* to a Collection in a for loop:

```
Dim inp As Integer
Dim counter As Integer
Dim n As node
Dim arr As Collection

Sub MySub()

    inp = InputBox("Insert a number: ")

    For counter = 2 To inp
        Set n = New node
        With n
            .value = counter
            .marked = False
        End With
        arr.Add n
    Next counter

End Sub
```

But when I try to run it it only says:

```
Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: You're missing a `Set arr = New Collection` line.

Comment: @Rory Wow thanks, that was simple..... Write it as Answer, so that I can tick it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a line before your loop:

```
Set arr = New Collection
```